# R: What is the faster way to read the table from data base?

Tags: r, performance, database-connection

R. I need to read table from MYsql faster. 
Now it used for connection:

```
conn <- dbPool(
drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
dbname = ............................)
```

and construction like this is used for read (and it takes more then 10 sec to exicute for only ~100 000 rows):

```
my_query <- sqlInterpolate(conn,"SELECT * from Ttable")
result <- dbGetQuery(conn,my_query)
```

Is there any way to read the table faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as a general rule for JDBC calls

1. Make sure your JDBC driver supports configuring fetch size
2. The fetch size should be based on your memory settings. (Try various values)
3. Go for prepared statements.